# Correlated sub Query in Amazon redshift

Tags: amazon-redshift

Issue that i am facing is Correlated sub Query working fine in Redshift **1.0.1564**  version , But the same query throws Amazon Invalid operation: This type of correlated subquery pattern is not supported due to internal error in Redshift **1.0.1657** version .

Any thoughts on this is highly appreciated

Below are the two difference version that i am holding for amazon redshit .

PostgreSQL 8.0.2 on i686-pc-linux-gnu, compiled by GCC gcc (GCC) 3.4.2 20041017 (Red Hat 3.4.2-6.fc3), Redshift **1.0.1657**

PostgreSQL 8.0.2 on i686-pc-linux-gnu, compiled by GCC gcc (GCC) 3.4.2 20041017 (Red Hat 3.4.2-6.fc3), Redshift **1.0.1564**

**Below is the query that i am using**

> select * , ( SELECT a.org_id  FROM derived.inv_org_d a  WHERE a.org_id
>   =b.org_id )  FROM derived.inv_org_d b

Comment: Please post the query.

Comment: Please **[EDIT]** your question and add the query you are using. [**Formatted text**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting) please, [no screen shots](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-may-i-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557). [edit] your question do not post code or additional information in comments

Comment: Without the query there isn't much to say. RedShift had done this to me before. Try VACUUM and ANALYSE on your tables, ensure you have the same distribution and sort keys, raise a ticket with Amazon. Then, even if you get it working,  find a way to simplify your query so it is less likely to break again in the future. Even if that involves breaking it into two and using staging tables.

Comment: I have add the code @MatBailie

Comment: looks like you're trying to do the join but it's unclear what you're trying to get here joining with the same table by id

Comment: Agreed. This could be done with a self join, for which RedShift would likely behave itself, but you're just selecting the value you joined on, which looks redundant?  *(If you have `b.id = a.id` then select `a.id`, why not just select `b.id`?)*